# EZ BUILD Bike Pedals

Tags: pedals

My granddaughter has one of these bikes, and she is 5 years old. She has the Huffy 20 inch Sea Star kids bike. One of her pink pedals his broken at the end of her pedal. She can still ride the bike for now, but I am afraid that where she has just learned how to ride without training wheels, she isn't used to a kick stand yet so sometimes she forgets about it and drops it. I would like to go ahead a purchase a new set of pedals before that happens but after reading your articles I'm afraid that you cannot replace them because of the way they are made and put together with a pin. I would really appreciate it if you let me know if there is any place that sells these pedals or if I can replace them with safer ones, if possible. If so, what type and size would the replaceable ones be? Are the ones that are on this bike from the factory 9/16 inch pedals or 12 inch pedals? Thank you for ever can help me

Answer (score 6):

I have an EZ BUILD bike so I checked.

You can replace the pedals, it does have standard 1/2 inch pedals.
Use a 15mm wrench.
Right pedal is right threaded (counter clockwise to remove)
Left pedal is left threaded (clockwise to remove).

[image]

Comment: Excellent work!  Thank you for checking.

Answer (score 4):

Just about all adult-sized bikes use 9/16" 20 TPI pedal thread.

Kids bikes may use 1/2" thread pedals (unsure of TPI on these offhand)

Your existing pedals are a minority that is unique to this brand because they use something else - a collar system with no threads in the crank arm.

[image] 


From:

Assembly instructional video.

Your options are:

1. Check on Walmart for spare parts for this bike.
2. Replace the whole bike  [which sells for $58 USD in December 2023.](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Huffy-20-in-Sea-Star-Kids-Bike-for-Girls-Ages-5-and-up-Child-Blue-and-Pink/272067876)
   Yes, our throw-away society strikes again.
3. Bodgery with taps and a welder.  Cludgery, if you prefer.  Certainly not cheapest.
4. Ride it as-is.

Depending on the age/height of the rider, you may be at the point where a larger frame is needed, if not now then soon.   This could be a convenient time to get a larger bike instead.  However a 5 year old is young for a 20" bike, so this may not be suitable.

Good luck!